# Why does my 2N7000 show a gate current of more than 4mA?

Tags: mosfet, leakage-current

I have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAiRBa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The D1 is in fact a character LCD backlight (with 4.2V input voltage and a maximum current of about 300mA). R2 is a peculiarity of my test setup, where I control the gate voltage using a potentiometer.

When measuring the current into the gate, I find that my multimeter shows 4mA to 5mA. The current drawn by the LCD with R1(*) in place like that is about 90 mA.

I wonder why there is such a large gate current. The datasheet of the 2N7000 suggests (but I might well be reading it wrong) that there should be a maximum of 10nA of gate current.

I tried the setup with two different voltage sources: A lab supply current-limited at 500mA and, after making sure that the setup doesn’t draw more than 100mA in total, 5V from my computers USB port. Both have shown the same behaviour.

(*): Don’t nail me on the value of R1. R1 is constructed of four 10Ω resistors in parallel, each with a tolerance of 10%. I just now measured 4Ω (8Ω before changing batteries on the multimeter) for that construct.

Comment: If you measure 8 Ohm for four 10 Ohm resistors in parallel there is reason to doubt your multimeter. Does it have a fresh battery? And: could you post a foto of your setup? Maybe you swapped the pins of the FET? And: when you disconnect the left line (+5v to gate), but leave R2 in place, does the LED current stop?

Comment: Right, changing the batteries made the measured resistance drop to 4Ω, which is probably way more in the tolerance region. When removing the +5V from the Gate/R2 net, the LED current stops (LEDs turn off). I double-checked FET pins, and according to datasheet it is shorted with a diode across S and D (so the LEDs should be always-on, no matter what happens on G).

Comment: To make this clear: after changing the batteries, the current measured is still roughly the same (4mA–5mA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gate of a MOSFET cannot drain 5mA current. If you said 5pA I could understand, but 5mA is practically and theoretically impossible.

Either;

- There is a leakage somewhere across the gate and source pins of the MOSFET.
- Your multimeter has a bias.
- The MOSFET is broken.
- There is a wrongly done connection around the gate.

Suggestions:

- Connect a gate resistor of 10\$\Omega\$ or 100\$\Omega\$. Send 1kHz, 0-5V pulses to the gate. If you can, amplify the voltage on the resistor by using an opamp difference amplifier. Observe the voltage drop on the resistor by using an oscilloscope (not with that multimeter).
- If you constructed your circuit on a breadboard, reconstruct it in a different region.

> The circuit is indeed constructed on a breadboard. Which effects would show this behaviour?

Dirt inside the breadboard structure my cause leakage current.

> I’m still open for blaming the multimeter though

You should. That's probably the only culprit.

> The FET seems to do what it is supposed to. Is there a failure mode which introduces such a large leak current but makes it still work correctly?

The system will still work if there is a ghost resistance between gate and source pins which will draw 5mA current. The system will still work even if that resister were very small in value as long as the power supply can supply enough current.

Comment: I don’t have the resources right now to perform your suggestions (at least not the first one). The circuit is indeed constructed on a breadboard. Which effects would show this behaviour? (I’m still open for blaming the multimeter though) The FET seems to do what it is supposed to. Is there a failure mode which introduces such a large leak current but makes it still work correctly? I might try with another multimeter later today.

Comment: Added the answers to my post.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience. I’ll let you know the results of the test with another multimeter (and with another MOSFET).

Comment: Ok, turns out it is not the multimeter. Replacing the FET removes the gate current.

Comment: I don't have any experience with the 2N7000, but some FETs will draw gate current. It depends on the process and how hard they are driven.

Comment: JFETs (J stands for Junction) and glassfets can draw gate current (or grid current), MOSFETs have insulated gates and cannot, unless broken. They ARE easy to break : as I commented once, you can get a lot of volts/metre across a micron...